# Function is undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function in onchange given to a text box. Whenever I focusout of a text box, the function should be called. But I'm getting myFunction(function name) is undefined. This is what I have done:

```
var c = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#table_projection_value").dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "includes/inc-projection-db.php?mode=projection_dataTable",
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [0],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return data + '<input type="hidden" class="user_id" name="user_id[]" id="user_id" value="' + row[4] + '">';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "aTargets": [1],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="text" onchange="myFunction();" class="form-control text-right projected_value" name="projected_value[]" id="projected_value_' + c + '_' + data + '" >';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                    c = c + 1;
                }
            });

        function myFunction(){
            $(":text").blur(function() {
            alert("**");
            var element=$(this); // you can get the element here
            });


            $(":text").focusout(function() {
            alert(this.id + " focus out");
            });
        }   
});
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

So the code within the jQuery function wont be directly accessable to you after the document is ready, you either move the function out of there or call your function in there:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  myFunc() {
    //code
  }
  // call here
})
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //code
})


   myFunc() {
    //code
  }
  // call here
```

Comment: Thanks dude, for your help. I got it. But now, I face another problem. I'm trying to get the value of that text box, where I get "TypeError: this.id.val is not a function" error. How to resolve this problem and get the value. This is what I've done:

Comment: function myFunction(){
   alert("Coming!");
   $(":text").blur(function() {
   
   var element=$(this); // you can get the element here
   });


   $(":text").focusout(function() {
   alert(this.id + " focus out");
   alert(("#this.id").val());
   //alert((this).val());
   });
  }

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your function out of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...})`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {...});
function myFunction(){
            $(":text").blur(function() {
            alert("**");
            var element=$(this); // you can get the element here
            });


            $(":text").focusout(function() {
            alert(this.id + " focus out");
            });
        }
```

Comment: I tried this. That error is gone, but I'm not getting that alert in that onchange. Why is that so?

Comment: Thanks dude, for your help. I got it. But now, I face another problem. I'm trying to get the value of that text box, where I get "TypeError: this.id.val is not a function" error. How to resolve this problem and get the value. This is what I've done:

Comment: function myFunction(){ alert("Coming!"); $(":text").blur(function() { var element=$(this); // you can get the element here }); $(":text").focusout(function() { alert(this.id + " focus out"); alert(("#this.id").val()); //alert((this).val()); }); }

Comment: You want to get the value of that textbox when blur?

Comment: function myFunction(){
            $("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
                var element=$(this);
                var value=element.val();
                console.log(value);
            });
        }
see console tab to see its value